# How do get a customlist adapter to work inside a fragment adapter?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

I am using a custom adapter to make a custom list containing text and buttons.
Now I need to have that view inside a fragment so I can easily switch between two different views.
But I can't seem to figure out how to add the activity inside the fragment code. Is it because I end up with an adapter inside another adapter?

Edit : My applicantsRequestActivity was made to test that the functionality of the custom list worked I just need to move that inside the fragment.

[image: My design]

My main activity

```
Activity (Label = "Main")]          
public class Test : FragmentActivity
{


    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SlidingTabScrollView mScrollView;


    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.FragMain);
        mScrollView = FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView> (Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        mViewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.viewPager);

        // setup mViewPager
        mViewPager.Adapter = new ApplicantsAdapter (SupportFragmentManager);
        mScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;


    }


}
```

My Fragment

```
public class ApplicantsAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> mFragmentHolder;

    public applicantsReqAdapter (Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragManager) : base (fragManager)
    {
        mFragmentHolder = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> ();
        mFragmentHolder.Add (new Applicants ());
        mFragmentHolder.Add (new Acceptes ());
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return mFragmentHolder.Count; }
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem (int position)
    {
        return mFragmentHolder [position];
    }
}

public class Applicants : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment 
{
    private EditText mTxt;

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Frag2Layout, container, false);

        mTxt = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText1);
        mTxt.Text = "Fragment 1 Class :)";
        return view;
    }

    public override string ToString () //Called on line 156 in SlidingTabScrollView
    {
        return "Fragment 1";
    }
}


public class Acceptes : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    private EditText mTxt;

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Frag2Layout, container, false);

        mTxt = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText1);
        mTxt.Text = "Fragment 2 Class :)";
        return view;
    }

    public override string ToString () //Called on line 156 in SlidingTabScrollView
    {
        return "Fragment 2";
    }
}
```

Here is what I need as the view for the first fragment

```
[Activity (Label = "Applicants")]           
public class applicantsRequestActivity : Activity
{
    DatabaseAccess db = new DatabaseAccess ();
    static ListView applicantsListView;
    static applicantsRequestAdapter listAdapter;
    static List<applicantsRequestList> applicantsList = new List<applicantsRequestList> ();


    //private ViewPager mViewPager;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource


    }


    public void GetApplicants ()
    {
        /*
         get the list from the database

        */


        applicantsList.Add (new PartyRequestList () { applicantsId = 1, Name = "James"});
        applicantsList.Add (new PartyRequestList () { applicantsId = 2, Name = "Thomas"});

    }

    bool isDownloaded = false;

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        base.OnStart ();

        applicantsListView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.PRR_listView);
        listAdapter = new applicantsRequestAdapter (this, applicantsList);
        applicantsListView.Adapter = listAdapter;

        if (!isDownloaded) {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => GetApplicants ());
            isDownloaded = true;
        }
    }           

    public class PartyRequestList
    {
        public int applicantsId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
    public class applicantsRequestAdapter : BaseAdapter<PartyRequestList>
    {
        private Button RemoveButton;
        private Button AcceptButton;
        private readonly IList<PartyRequestList> _items;
        private readonly Context _context;

        public applicantsRequestAdapter (Context context, IList<PartyRequestList> items)
        {
            _items = items;
            _context = context;
        }

        public override long GetItemId (int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override int Count {
            get { return _items.Count; }
        }

        public override applicantsRequestList this [int position] {
            get { return _items [position]; }
        }

        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = _items [position];
            var view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                var inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext (_context);
                view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.applicantsRequestRow, parent, false);

                RemoveButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.PRR_Remove);
                AcceptButton = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.PRR_Accept);
                RemoveButton.Tag = position;
                AcceptButton.Tag = position;
                RemoveButton.Click += RemoveButton_Click;
                AcceptButton.Click += AcceptButton_Click;
            }

            view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.PRR_Name).Text = item.Name;                
            return view;
        }

        void RemoveButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pos = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;
            PartyRequestList _aa = applicantsList [pos];
            Toast.MakeText (_context, (String.Format ("Remove: {0} {1}", _aa.Name, pos)), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            applicantsList.RemoveAt (pos);
            NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        }

        void AcceptButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pos = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;
            PartyRequestList _aa = applicantsList [pos];
            Toast.MakeText (_context, (String.Format ("Accept: {0} {1}", _aa.Name, pos)), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        }
    }
}
```

Main axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E2E2E2"
    android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <SlidingTabLayout.SlidingTabScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

the 2 axml I use for my custom list

The list axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/PRR_listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The row axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PRR_Name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Name" />
<Button
    android:text="Remove"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/PRR_Remove"
    android:tag="Remove" />
<Button
    android:text="Accept"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/PRR_Accept"
    android:tag="Accept" />
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My code is Java not C#. FYI

What functionality are you trying to keep inside your fragment exactly? 
Unfortunately I don't think you're able to get the full functionality of your activity inside the fragment but you can access it with for getActivity, for example:

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setText("Title Bar Text here");
```

or directly like:

```
MainActivity.staticMethod()
```

Here is myListFragment class

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private customList = new ListAdapater<RowItem>;
private static ListView projectListView;


public MyListFragment() {
}

public void add(View view)
{
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(newIntent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (DB/JSON Object) and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    // Get current list adapter from main and set it here to the rootview for this
    // list fragment
    //userDataAdapter = MainActivity.getListAdapter();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);
    projectListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    //Fill in list data
    if (mySnapshot != null) {
        for (DataSnapshot project : mySnapshot.getChildren() ) {
            if (project.child("Name").getValue() != null) {

                //Get Project Details from Firebase JSON
                String pName = project.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                String pDesc = project.child("Description").getValue().toString();
                int statusImageId = Utility.getStatusImage(Integer.parseInt(project.child("Status").getValue().toString()));

                //Create RowItem for ArrayList
                RowItem proj = new RowItem(statusImageId, pName, pDesc);

                //Add RowItem to the adapter arraylist
                customList.add(proj);
            }

        }
    }

    //set custom list
    projectListView.setAdapter(customList);

    //Set list click listener, if an item is clicked(selected) then we will change view
    //to the nexst list
    projectListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            //Handle list item clicks here.
        }
    });      
    return rootView;
}
```

}

And here is what my custom adapter looks like:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
//Context for the current view
Context context;


public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_layout, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * getView method returns the individual row views inflated so they can be displayed in the list
 * @param position position of the RowItem being requested in the ArrayList
 * @param convertView view to hold the entire row view before it is passed back to the ListView
 * @param parent reference to the ListView where the row will be shown.
 * @return view is given back to the listView so only displayed items + 1 on each side will stay
 *          android in memory
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    txtDesc.setText(getItem(position).getDesc());
    txtTitle.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
    imageView.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImageId());
    return view;
}
```

}

My RowItem class just has two strings for title/desc and an in to hold the image_id reference.

It should be noted that the fragment is launched with the following inside my MainActivity:
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new MyListFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

Other files:

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
/>
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight = "1"
/>
<!-- Add Button -->
<Button android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:onClick="add"
    android:text="Add New"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Code added - hopefully I didn't miss anything.

Edit: Here is the link to this project on github https://github.com/thurst0n/Archie It might make more sense there but please ignore my bad coding practices, much of this was thrown together for school.  I remember specifically having issues initially getting a listview working in a fragment and not just a plain activity. Also note that I simply swap out list adapters for each level instead of creating another instance of my list fragment, this was a design choice to make other features easier to implement but probably not good design practice. I think the proper way to do it would be let the fragmentmanager handle the backstack.

```
//Use this for something?
public void setContent(Fragment fragment)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new MyListFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I made the activity to test the custom list. I just need the functionality of the activity inside the fragment. and I don't now how to add the custom adapter inside the fragmet adapter.

Comment: Hopefully something I put here helps. I was tackling a very similar issue.